# Handbrake doesn't keep Hi10p and HEVC after conversion

Tags: video-conversion, matroska, video-encoding, handbrake

**Handbrake** is a great tool for me to convert media files. I noticed that my original video file (mkv, 1080p, Hi10p, HEVC) lose some quality after conversion (mp4, 1080p, 8-bit, AVC). What I've converted are Mp4 extension, Variable Framerate, Avg bitrate:1000 kbps, 2-pass Encoding. How am I going to maintain Hi10p and HEVC during conversion? 
I heard that Handbrake doesn't support Hi10p, is there any ways to convert videos and keep Hi10p and HEVC?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic. Handbrake supports HEVC, but you need to select it. You might be able to create a custom profile for Hi10 somehow.

Comment: Where to select HEVC? I don't see Hi10 option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Video Codec "H.265(x265)", then under H.265 Profile Select "Main10"
then under Container select "MP4".   Try that, if you still lose some quality try upping the Avg bitrate.

If you are trying to go to H.264 from HEVC, then use H.264 Profile High and double your avg bitrate.

Comment: Ohh ya!!! Why I didn't see that !!